# how to test on real system images from Android OEMs?

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion, rom

I use [Genymotion Emulator](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/) for testing in different Android Version. Genymotion has System images that are labelled as from different OEMs like Samsung, LG, Sony, etc. but they are really just the same image.

Is there any way to test on actual System Images from different Android OEMs - i.e. real images that they are putting on their phones? like - I want to use the actual Lollipop image that LG is putting on its LG G3 with its custom skin.

I am finding several issues (reported from users and later confirmed by me) that I have confirmed are due to the difference in the system images (and not dependent on the hardware).

I am OK even if these custom OEM images are downloadable from somewhere that I have to flash on a real device - how to find these images?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to test on different devices is to use different devices. That being said, I'm sure you could find versions of OEM Android builds on http://www.xda-developers.com/ but they would probably be somewhat modified.